# Cannot Create Forge Gradle Workspace

Tags: gradle, gradlew, minecraft-forge

So, basically, I'm trying to work on a Minecraft 1.12.2 mod. I downloaded the 1.12.2 Forge MDK file and un-zipped it. Whenever I try to run: `./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace`, I just get this error:

Whole output: https://pastebin.com/rCGNKC6T

And it just says BUILD FAILED in 20s after that. What can I do to solve this?

I am using a MacBook Pro 10.13

- Java version "1.8.0_251"
- JRE & JDK Versions 8u251

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You didn't post the whole output. Please add all of it, not just the part you think is important.

Comment: Ok, I added the whole output.

Comment: Which MDK zip did you get exactly? In particular, which forge version?